# Android implement number cover background effect

Tags: android

I want to implement this [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMgfi.png) on my android app, what i think is put the heart ImageView as background and numbers TextView on the foreground. But i can't draw the border of the number with a good effect. How do i implement this effect?

Answer (score 0):

consider using shadow under letters in `TextView` with

```
android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
android:shadowRadius="4"
```

or

```
textView.setShadowLayer(4, 0, 0, Color.WHITE);
```